# Windows 8.1 PC keeps running a search

Tags: windows, keyboard, search

I'm having this weird issue where my computer (or whatever causes it) keeps hitting ctrl+f on its own. This means that if I am on desktop, the search files side menu keeps popping up, and if in a browser it always triggers the search bar. It also seems to affect the arrow keys (and maybe even more keys? Hard to tell)

This behavior keeps happening after a restart, shut down, safe mode and a virus scan, right after I log into my user.

My keyboard is still working, but after most of the strokes this search bug takes over and I can no longer write.  It also seems to control to some degree the selection of text.

I cannot recall installing something new as recently and nothing new is plugged to my pc.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps it's just a faulty keyboard.  Did it do it while in safe mode as well?  If you unplug your keyboard (and/or try a different, known-good one) does it problem continue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the solution was simple. Had a wireless keyboard and mouse, and even when I unplugged them their usb transmitters was plugged in and caused all the problem.